# Why doesn't doas wget -qO- archive.tar.gz|doas tar -xz work as with sudo?

Tags: sudo, pipe, tar, doas

`sudo wget -qO- https://go.dev/dl/go1.20.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz|sudo tar -xz` works fine.

`doas wget -qO- https://go.dev/dl/go1.20.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz|doas tar -xz` does not work. I get no input, it just freezes on me. I'm able to run other, simpler, commands with `doas`.

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (I installed `doas` with `apt install doas`) and my `/etc/doas.conf` is `permit jim as root`.

Why doesn't the command with `doas` work as with `sudo`?
Do I need to further configure `doas` for the command to work?

Comment: This seems to be a known issue in the Linux port of `doas` - see [password is read from stdin, not TTY](https://github.com/slicer69/doas/issues/17)

Comment: I don't think the first half of the pipe needs doas or sudo.

Comment: Is the password persisted for a short while with your `doas` configuration, or does it ask for a password every single time no matter how recently you last authenticated?

Comment: @Kusalananda I does not persist, it asks me every single time.